# eslint in VS Code not highlighting undeclared variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I was playing around with my extensions and settings a while ago and have been struggling to get my linter to show the old warnings and errors it had. At the moment, I'm not getting any highlighting for undeclared variables. Would anyone mind talking me through how to figure this out, as I've hit a wall.

I have the eslint extension installed. I've also installed eslint with `npm install...` and have a `.eslintrc.json` file with the following settings:

```json
    {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended","eslint:recommended"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 11,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
    },
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 1,
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    }}
```

I have a `settings.json` file with the following:

```json
{...
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
    "prettier.printWidth": 130,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
...}
```

Comment: Your ESLint configuration is invalid. You should remove the `jdDeletedRules` property

I have installed `eslint`, `eslint-plugin-react` and tested your ESLint configuration. Did I miss anything else?

Comment: Thanks Ngo, I've just deleted that. I've actually closed and opened my VS Code and it's now behaving completely different. I have previously been using the ```VS Code > Command Pallete > Developer: Reload Window ``` command, thinking that it was restarting eslint, but apparently not!

Comment: Ngo, it seems to all be working correctly now, thank you. It was just me not understanding how the reload button worked I think. Thanks again for going to so much trouble.

Comment: You are welcome. In your case, I would restart the eslint server only. All I did was create a project with eslint, eslint-plugin-react, an eslint configuration file, a js file. The eslint extension of VSCode detected the invalid property for me.